# How to retrieve ONE column from another table with Foreign key using Hibernate / JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I would like to use the Foreign key "`MODEL_ID`" to retrieve just one column "`MODEL_NAME`" from the TT_CARS table,
I tried the following code, that works but it returns the whole CARS object.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "MODEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private CARS cars;
```

Also I tried the code below, its also not working

```
@SecondaryTable(name = "TT_CARS", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName="MODEL_ID"))
```

Is there other way to retieve just the column (`MODEL_NAME`) using hibernate and JPA??

remarks: The modelName should be part of the `Options` class.

my code

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TT_OPTIONS")
public class Options  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "MODEL_ID") // Foreign key
    private Long modelId;

    @Column(name = "MODEL_NAME", table = "TT_CARS") // this is the column name I would like to retrieve from the TT_CARS table
    private String modelName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html). It is read-only calculated column that can be retrieved by the custom subquery. It does not present in the target table.

> Defines a formula (derived value) which is a SQL fragment that acts as
> a @Column alternative in most cases. Represents read-only state.

Example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TT_OPTIONS")
public class Options  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "MODEL_ID") 
    private Long modelId;

    @Formula("(select TT_CARS.MODEL_NAME from TT_CARS where TT_CARS.ID = MODEL_ID)")
    private String modelNameFormula;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TT_CARS")
public class Cars {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "MODEL_NAME")
    private String modelName;
}
```

Hibernate generated native query:

```sql
    select
        options0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        options0_.description as descript2_4_0_,
        options0_.model_id as model_id3_4_0_,
        (select
            TT_CARS.MODEL_NAME 
        from
            TT_CARS 
        where
            TT_CARS.ID = options0_.MODEL_ID) as formula1_0_ 
    from
        tt_options options0_ 
    where
        options0_.id=?
```

[@SecondaryTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) designed for @OneToOne relationship to map multiple tables to the same entity. It will not work for the @ManyToOne relationship.